# how to apply downloadable fonts to whole app at run time?

Tags: android, fonts, android-custom-view, android-8.0-oreo, android-downloadable-fonts

I want to implement Android [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) in my app and give user option to choose from multiple fonts and change every layout and views(be it toolbar, navigation view, dialog etc.) font immediately user has selected any font. Is there some easy and less time consuming way out for this.